# How to fetch session id using reqular expression

Tags: jmeter

Hi I want to fetch a session id from following response using reqular expression

```
<form id="fm1" action="/cas/login;jsessionid=08D3BEEBAAB30126106472355249AB49" method="post">
```

I want output as `jsessionid=08D3BEEBAAB30126106472355249AB49`
I have tried many way, but not working 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Regular Expression Extractor configured as follows:

**Field to check**: Body

**Reference Name**: anything meaningful, i.e. sessionId

**Regular Expression**: jsessionid=(\d\w+)

**Template**: $1$

Answer (score 0):

try going through jmeter wiki, the latest one covers in a very good and generic way

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Use following regular expression: `jsessionid=(.+?)"`

[image: Regex JSESSIONID]

By the way, you can test regex against real response using RegExp Tester option of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

By the way, there is an easier option to capture JSESSIONID value. In majority of cases it is a [HTTP Cookie](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/listtutorial/What-is-JSESSIONID-Cookie-in-J2EE-web-applications/4214) hence you can easily access it's value using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

1. Add the following line to *user.properties* file (it's located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter
3. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
4. Access captured cookie value as `${COOKIE_JSESSIONID}` where required.

See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) article for more detailed explanation of the importance of this configuration element.